# Hibernate + JPA + spring boot org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Boot 4, Hibernate and JPA annotations. I ran into this error

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist.

I tried searching through the internet and couldn't quite get the proper answer. I tried to use `merge` instead of `persist` and it did not work. Besides I think `merge` is used when updating a resource.

Here is my code:

`

```
package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;

import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.userconstants.UserRepositoryConstants;

@NamedQueries({
      @NamedQuery(name = UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_GET_ALL_USERS,
          query = UserRepositoryConstants.QUERY_GET_ALL_USERS),
      @NamedQuery(name = UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_GET_USER_BY_ID,
      query = UserRepositoryConstants.QUERY_GET_USER_BY_ID),
      @NamedQuery(name = UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_GET_USER_BY_USERNAME,
      query = UserRepositoryConstants.QUERY_GET_USER_BY_USERNAME),
      @NamedQuery(name = UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_DELETE_USER,
      query = UserRepositoryConstants.QUERY_DELETE_USER)
})

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String username;
    String password;
    String phone;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

`
CRUD service

`

```
package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.CRUDService;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.model.User;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.repository.UserRepository;


@Service
@Transactional
public class UserCRUDService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public User createUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }

    public User updateUser(User user) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.getUserById(user.getId());

        if (existingUser == null) {
           throw new NoResultException();
        }

        existingUser.setId(user.getId());
        existingUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        existingUser.setPhone(user.getPhone());
        existingUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        userRepository.update(user);
        return user;
    }

    public User deleteUser(long id) {
        User user = userRepository.getUserById(id);

        if (user == null) {
          throw new NoResultException();
        }

        userRepository.delete(user);
        return user;
    }

}
```

`

Repository

`

```
    package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.repository;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.model.User;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.userconstants.UserRepositoryConstants;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserRepository extends AbstractRepository<User> {
    TypedQuery<User> query;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_GET_ALL_USERS, User.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public User getUserById(long id) {
        query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_GET_USER_BY_ID, User.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }

    public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
        query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(UserRepositoryConstants.NAME_GET_USER_BY_USERNAME, User.class);
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        return query.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

`
Abstract repository

`

```
package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void save(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.refresh(entity);
    }

    @Transactional
    public T update(T entity) {
        return entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

`

Factory
`

```
 package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.factories;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.BackingForm.UserBackingForm;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.model.User;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.viewmodels.UserViewModel;

@Service
public class UserFactory {

    public UserViewModel createViewModel(User user) {
        UserViewModel viewModel = new UserViewModel();
        viewModel.setId(user.getId());
        viewModel.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        viewModel.setPhone(user.getPhone());
        return viewModel;
    }

    public List<UserViewModel> createVewModels(List<User> users) {
        List<UserViewModel> viewModels = new ArrayList<>();

        if (users != null) {
          for (User user : users) {
              viewModels.add(createViewModel(user));
          }
        }
        return viewModels;
    }

    public User createEntity(UserBackingForm userBackingForm) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(userBackingForm.getId());
        user.setUsername(userBackingForm.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(userBackingForm.getPassword());
        user.setPhone(userBackingForm.getPhone());
        return user;
    }

}
```

`
Backing form

`

```
package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.BackingForm;

public class UserBackingForm {
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String phone;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

`

Controller

`

```
package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.BackingForm.UserBackingForm;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.CRUDService.UserCRUDService;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.factories.UserFactory;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.model.User;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.repository.UserRepository;
import com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.viewmodels.UserViewModel;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserCRUDService userCRUDService;
    @Autowired
    private UserFactory userFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Object> getAllUsers() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("users", userRepository.getAllUsers());
        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, Object> getUserById(@PathVariable long id) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("user", userRepository.getUserById(id));
        return map;
    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/user/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public UserViewModel addUser(@RequestBody UserBackingForm form) {
    User user = userFactory.createEntity(form);
    //user.setIsActive(true);
    user = userCRUDService.createUser(user);
    return userFactory.createViewModel(user);
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/add/{id}", method =    RequestMethod.PUT)
public Map<String, Object> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody User user) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    user.setId(id);
    map.put("updatedUser", userCRUDService.updateUser(user));
    return map;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testFinal() {
    return "User test sucessfully";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    User user = userRepository.getUserById(id);
    userRepository.delete(user);
}
```

}

`

View Model

`

```
  package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.viewmodels;

public class UserViewModel extends BaseViewModel<Long> {
    private String username;
    private String phone;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

`

base ViewModel

```
`
  package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.viewmodels;

public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> {

  private T id;

  public T getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(T id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((getId() == null) ? 0 : getId().hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    BaseViewModel<T> other = (BaseViewModel<T>) obj;
    if (getId() == null) {
      if (other.getId() != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!getId().equals(other.getId()))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

}
```

`

Main

```
`    


  package com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class,args);

    }

}
```

`
Stack Trace

```
`

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.matome.users.login.stats.springbootStarter.model.User
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the problem lies in the fact that you have declared the `id` of `User` entity as auto-generated:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;
```

and when you create the User object you set the id manually:

```
 public User createEntity(UserBackingForm userBackingForm) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(userBackingForm.getId());
    ...
```

and thus when you pass that to `persist` / `save`, the Persistence Provider will not allow that as it expects that the `id` will not be set by the client.

**The bottom line** is that you should not set the `id` regarding the current configuration when you are aiming at persisting a new entry and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Maciej thanks for your sugestion. I removed the auto-generation and added this :`
     user.setId(form.getId());
     user = userCRUDService.createUser(user);
     return userFactory.createViewModel(user);
  `

Comment: The above modifications resulted in this exception `"exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
    "message": "could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into user (password, phone, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

Comment: remember to remove Transactional  annotation from UserRepository as you already made the service transactional

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The problem was that the DB(derby) confused the user table with another default build in user table. I made changes in the pom from derby to h2 db and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a full stack trace ?

Some hints for you : 
You should only set @Transactional at Service level, not dao / repository.

Entitymanager refresh method means get data from DB to recreate an entity. If you just persist the entity, there is no need to refresh it.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public void save(T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();  //  This is not really usefull on a small transaction
    entityManager.refresh(entity); // No need for that : persist means entity already in sync
}
```

On update side, if you have a managed entity there is no need to sync it back to the DB, JPA take care of that automatically. (and merge push entity in the db forcing an update of all column) :

```
public User updateUser(User user) {
    User existingUser = userRepository.getUserById(user.getId());

    // ...
    existingUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    // ...
    userRepository.update(user);  // This is not needed !
    return user;
}
```

If you want simplest things, you should take a look at lombok. It will help you write simpliest bean ( @Data to generate getter/setter ...)
You use Spring, so take also a look at spring-Data-JPA, It writes for you some cumberstone code.

Comment: Hi Wargre I have edited the question to include the stack trace. Thanks for the suggestion I will try lombok.